# How to select multiple selected choice in dropdown using Javascript with specific delimiter

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get the value of dropdown of multiple selection in the dropdown .

```js
// dropdown display

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
    <select id="MMCONO" name="MMCONO" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true">
                               
                               <option value="">Select cono</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option>
                                <option value="900">900</option>
                                <option value="200">200</option>

    </select>
```

```
// get the value of only selected choice 

 const MMCONO = document.getElementById('MMCONO').value;
```

I'm trying to get multiple choice of the dropdown and get the result as such  if all multiple choices are selected:

*output would be  :*

**['100' , '200' , '900']**

Comment: A drop down is not the typical or best tool for multiple choice selection, it would be better to use a checklist and allow for multiple checkboxes to be selected. As your code is written there's no way for multiple choices to be selected.

Comment: Maybe add multiple attribute to select multiple?

Comment: @Ryan  how to do that do you have an exemple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function handleChange(){
  let select = document.querySelector('#MMCONO')
  let values = Array.prototype.map.call(select.selectedOptions,(e => e.value))
  console.log(values)
}
```

```html
<select id="MMCONO" name="MMCONO" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true" onchange="handleChange()" multiple>
      <option value="">Select cono</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="900">900</option>
      <option value="200">200</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This does not let the user select multiple options, it just gets all the options in the select and puts them in an array.

Comment: How to use checklist @ryan

Comment: @Alan omar thns for your response but as ryan said it will get all the options and pût them in an array and that not the wanted result

Comment: @Ryan i fixed it for you.